# Invoking toLocaleString() in UTC

Tags: javascript

I have a variable `d` of type `Date` and value `'2017-05-01T01:00:00.000Z'`.

My time zone is UTC-4.

When I invoke:

```
 d.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "short" });
```

I get `Apr`, because the date is Apr 30, 2017 2100h UTC-4 where my Javascript is running.

Is there an easy way to get `toLocaleString` to treat the date instance according to its UTC equivalent?

Comment: Are you saying you'd like to be able to render the date as though your system were in GMT?

Comment: Yes, if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can [specify a parameter `timeZone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), which defines the target timezone to be used when formatting the date:

```js
var date = new Date('2017-05-01T01:00:00.000Z');

console.log(date.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "short", timeZone: 'America/New_York' }));
  // "Apr"

console.log(date.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "short", timeZone: 'UTC' }));
  // "May"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Adjust date to UTC 0
d = new Date(d.valueOf() + d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
d.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "short" })
```

*UPDATE*  [@Timo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42956281/5651) is way better.